# Airflow - Test a TaskGroup

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, airflow-webserver

Is there a way to test all tasks within a TaskGroup in Airflow without running each task separately?

I have multiple task groups within a dag. I don't want to test the whole dag. I also don't want to have to test the tasks individually. See below for an example.

```
with DAG(
    dag_id="sample_dag",
    default_args=default_args,
    description="Refresh the data",
    schedule_interval=timedelta(hours=2),
    start_date=datetime(2022, 1, 1),
    catchup=False,
    # tags=['dataset'],
) as dag1:

    with TaskGroup("test", tooltip="Check Elasticsearch Connections") as test:

        es_conn_cl = BashOperator(
            task_id="es_conn_cl",
            bash_command=(
                "python -m unittest test_conn.EsTestCases.test_client_connection"
            ),
            cwd="/opt/airflow/tasks/test",  # TODO: Parameterize this
        )

        es_conn_sr = BashOperator(
            task_id="es_conn_sr",
            bash_command=(
                "python -m unittest test_conn.EsTestCases.test_server_connection"
            ),
            cwd="/opt/airflow/tasks/test",  # TODO: Parameterize this
        )

        internet_conn = BashOperator(
            task_id="internet_conn",
            bash_command=("python -m unittest test_conn.InternetTestCases; exit 0"),
            cwd="/opt/airflow/tasks/test",  # TODO: Parameterize this
        )

    TaskGroup2
    TaskGroup3
    Etc...
```

Comment: Task Groups are just a UI grouping concept. what do you want exactly to test ?

Comment: I want to test all tasks within the task group. For this example, something like airflow tasks test <task_group>.

Comment: I don't see a way to do it out of the box. You can test all dag or via api get all task aggeregate it by name and run the tests